# sql query to count two type in single cloumn

Tags: sql

```
BUSES
----------------
|BUS_NO    
|BUS_NAME
|TYPE
|AVAIL_SEAT
```

I have to calculate how many `AC` and `NON AC` buses are there?

My query for `count` is:

```
count(*)bus_count
sum(case when type='ac' then 1 else 0)
sum (case when type="non ac" then 1 else 0)
from buses
group by bus_number;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the content inside a database table are case sensitive adding lower or upper function will convert the content of the type attribute to lower or upper case and will try to match it with the value given. Here I have used lower function but upper function can also be used then we'll have to give the type value as 'AC'/'NON AC'.

```
SELECT 
    type AS bus_type,
    CASE
        WHEN LOWER(type) = 'ac' THEN COUNT(type)
        WHEN LOWER(type) = 'non ac' THEN COUNT(type)
    END AS bus_count
FROM
    buses
GROUP BY type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are only 2 values in 'type' column, following query will work:

```
Select type, 
Count (*) as bus_count
From bus
Group by 1;
```

---

Answer (score 0):

If you need  the two result on the same column   you a need only a  sum as

```
 select  
      sum( case when type ='ac' then 1 else 0 end ) type_ac
    , sum( case when type <>'ac' then 1 else 0 end ) type_not_ac
  from buses
```

if you need   a list for type the Hemant answer  is what you need

Answer (score 0):

```
select type as bus_type,
case when type='ac' then count(type)
     when type='non ac' then count(type) end bus_count
from buses group by type;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
select type as bus_type,count(bus_no) as bus_count 
from buses
group by type
order by bus_count desc;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!

Answer (score 0):

```
select type as bus_type, 

case 

when type='ac' then count(type)

when type='non ac' then count(type)

end as bus_count

from buses

group by bus_type

order by bus_count desc;
```

Comment: Please provide more detail explaining why your answer helps and / or solves the OP.